# How to create an immutable map/set from a seq?

Tags: scala, immutability

I am try to construct immutable Sets/Maps from a Seq.  I am currently doing the following:

```
val input: Seq[(String, Object)] = //.....
Map[String, Object]() ++ input
```

and for sets

```
val input: Seq[String] = //.....
Set[String]() ++ input
```

Which seems a little convoluted, is there a better way?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

In Scala 2.8:

```
Welcome to Scala version 2.8.0.r20327-b20091230020149 (Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM, Java 1.6.
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.

scala> val seq: Seq[(String,Object)] = ("a","A")::("b","B")::Nil
seq: Seq[(String, java.lang.Object)] = List((a,A), (b,B))

scala> val map = Map(seq: _*)
map: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,java.lang.Object] = Map(a -> A, b -> B)

scala> val set = Set(seq: _*)
set: scala.collection.immutable.Set[(String, java.lang.Object)] = Set((a,A), (b,B))

scala>
```

**Edit 2010.1.12**

I find that there is a more simple way to create set.

```
scala> val seq: Seq[(String,Object)] = ("a","A")::("b","B")::Nil
seq: Seq[(String, java.lang.Object)] = List((a,A), (b,B))

scala> val set = seq.toSet
set: scala.collection.immutable.Set[(String, java.lang.Object)] = Set((a,A), (b,B))
```

Comment: `val map = Map(seq: _*)` gave me that "scala feeling" in my stomach again :) Thanks

Comment: Drowning in underscores and special characters in general?

Comment: Please look also at Chris' answer which features toMap in addition to toSet.

Answer (score 16):

To convert a `Seq` to a `Map`, simply call `toMap` on the `Seq`. Note that the elements of the `Seq` must be `Tuple2` ie. `(X,Y)` or `(X->Y)`

```
scala> val seq: Seq[(String,String)] = ("A","a")::("B","b")::("C","c")::Nil
seq: Seq[(java.lang.String, java.lang.String)] = List((A,a), (B,b), (C,c))

scala> seq.toMap
res0: scala.collection.immutable.Map[java.lang.String,java.lang.String] = Map((A,a), (B,b), (C,c))
```

To convert a `Seq` to a `Set`, simply call `toSet` on the `Seq`.

```
scala> val seq: Seq[String] = "a"::"b"::"c"::Nil
seq: Seq[java.lang.String] = List(a, b, c)

scala> seq.toSet
res1: scala.collection.immutable.Set[java.lang.String] = Set(a, b, c)
```